# How to make an array of PictureBoxes in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

**How do I make an array of PictureBoxes in Visual Basic?**

I'm trying to make a row of PictureBoxes -that's all the same size, and same picture- to display across the form. How could I do this?

I made the array using this:

```
Dim blk(10) As PictureBox
```

and the code to place the PictureBoxes is this:

```
'Create PictureBoxes
    blk(0) = blk_Green()
    blk(0).Image = imgl_blk.Images(0)
    blk(0).Visible = True
    blk(0).SetBounds(10, 10, blk_Green.Width, blk_Green.Height)
    For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
        blk(i) = blk_Green()
        blk(i).Image = imgl_blk.Images(0)
        blk(i).Visible = True
        blk(i).SetBounds(i * 10, 10, blk_Green.Width, blk_Green.Height)'I will change this according to what it needs to be
    Next
```

*imgl_blk* is an ImageList, and *blk_Green* is a ImageBox I've already made on the form.

When I run it, only one of the PictureBoxes will show up, instead of all 10 from the array.

This is what i'm trying to get (Or something like this):
[image: What i'm trying to get]

This is what happens instead:
[image: What Happens]

How could I make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a control array:

```
Dim blk() As PictureBox

blk = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4}
```

Then you can reference PictureBox1 with blk(0), PictureBox2 with blk(1), PictureBox3 with blk(2) and PictureBox4 with blk(3).

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the same `Object`'s reference to all 10 PictureBoxes. You need to instantiate each one of your PictureBoxes separately and then assign each one's `Image` property.

BTW, you should really look into GDI+'s drawing methods such as [Graphics.DrawImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) to do this kind of stuff. It would be a lot faster and less of a memory-hog.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this :

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Shapes(10) As PictureBox
    For i = 1 To 10

        Shapes(i) = New PictureBox
        Shapes(i).Name = "rect" + Str(i)
        Shapes(i).BackColor = Color.Green

        Shapes(i).Location = New Point(10 + 50 * i, 20)
        Shapes(i).Size = New Size(40, 20)
        Shapes(i).Visible = True
        Me.Controls.Add(Shapes(i))
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you provide a little context to this?  How does this solve the issue?

Comment: This code creates array of 10 picture boxes dynamically and assign a name to them as rect1,rect2,.....,and locate them in a row.I edit the size from (50,20) to (40,20). I don't assign image to them

Comment: Just create a new vb project and paste this code in Form1.vb and  run.